# Screen optimization for tablets

Tags: java, android, android-layout, optimization, padding

I have optimized my app for just about all Android phones.  The way my app is set up, I have a 16dp padding on the left and right side of it and a 65dp padding on top and bottom (see screenshot below).  On a phone it looks beautiful.

But on a tablet, it looks terrible.  65dp on a phone is a whole lot different that 65dp on a tablet.  On a tablet, the black border around the question runs off the side of the scroll background and stuff is on the roll at the top and bottom of the scroll background.

What are my options to fix this?  Is there a percentage/weight option for padding?  I think that would solve it completely but there is nothing like that that I know of.

[image]

Comment: 65 dp is supposed to be about the same on all screens-  it's approximately 65/160th of an inch, although it may be slightly bigger or smaller due to rounding.  But if you really want help, post your layout file and a picture of what it looks like on the phone and tablet so we can compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create multiple resource files tailored for different display sizes. Android will automatically choose the correct resource file for you. Using this technique, you can specify padding values for any screen size, or even completely unique layouts, to be automatically selected for you by Android.

Please refer to [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).

Using multiple dimension resource files would make the task of changing the padding based on screen size very simple. See [More Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: I did not know I could set "qualifiers" and do multiple layouts for small, regular, large and x-large screens.  I am going to go that route.